# How do i prove that there are at least 12 faces of degree 5 for a regular graph of degree 3 where there are no faces of degree less than five,

Tags: graph-theory

how would i go about proving this?

Using the handshaking lemma, the sum of the vertex degrees = 2m.

So, we have $3n = 2m$.

Using Euler's Formula : $n-m+f = 2, $ we have $\frac{2}{3}m - m +f = 2$

$\Rightarrow f -  \frac{1}{3}m = 2 $.

Im unsure where to go from here.

Comment: I take it the graph must be planar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you count the length of each face, you will count each edge twice. Let $f_i$ denote the number of faces of length $i$. Then \begin{align*} 2m&=5f_5+6f_6+7f_7+\cdots\\&\geq 5f_5+6f_6+6f_7+\cdots\\ &= 5f_5+6(f_6+f_7+\cdots)\\&=5f_5 + 6(f-f_5) \\ & = 6f-f_5.\end{align*}

So $f_5\geq 6f-2m$. Now use what you derived already: $f=2+\frac{1}{3}m$.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! so to calculate the number of vertices of a graph which had for example all faces of degree 5, how would i calculate this? I have that $ f \le \frac{2}{5}m$ by the handshaking lemma... what else do i need to use?

Comment: Well you have $n=2+m-f$, $2m=5f$ and $m=\frac{3}{2}n$. Also, this is the 9th question you've asked on this site and you've accepted zero answers.  Please [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).